# Cannot fortify rworldmap's default world map with a region argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the default world map from `rworldmaps` as a background layer for a bunch of plots done with `ggplot2`.  In order to do this I have to "fortify" the object returned by `getMap()` - this converts it to a format ggplot understands.

Given

```
> library(maptools)
> library(rworldmap)
> library(ggplot2)
```

and the 'rgeos' package also installed, this works, but gives me a message which makes it sound like I really ought to specify the "region=" argument:

```
> world <- fortify(getMap())
Regions defined for each Polygons
```

I want the background layer to show country borders, so I *think* I ought to specify `region="ADMIN"`, but this fails:

```
> world <- fortify(getMap(), region="ADMIN")
Error: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form
a closed linestring
```

I get the same error message for other plausible region= settings (NAME, ISO_A2, REGION, continent, etc).

What is going on and what is the correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with the region argument, in this case it means your features get unioned together based on the "ADMIN" grouping. With ggplot aesthetics you don't need to do this kind of union, you can just change the colours etc. (Unless you want to show polygon borders and *not show* the internal ones where polygons are grouped . . .)

`rgeos` gets invoked here to do the union, and for whatever reason there is a geometric detail that it doesn't like. (Please see the new `sf` package now on CRAN for the future of these tools in R, it's all different but that's where things are going).

I would just stick with ggplot2 aesthetics to "display the grouping":

```
library(maptools)
library(rworldmap)
library(ggplot2)

w <- getMap()
## we need to id to join back
w$id_1 <- row.names(w)
world <- fortify(w)

library(dplyr)
world <- world %>% inner_join(as.data.frame(w)[, c("ADMIN", "id_1")], c("id" = "id_1"))

ggplot(world) + aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = ADMIN) + geom_polygon() + guides(fill = FALSE)
```

In this case ADMIN and row.names are the same, so it's a bit pointless to join, but the general case would work as well.